# Focus the property sheet in Access 2010

Tags: microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2010

Is there any keyboard shortcut in Access 2010 to focus the property sheet?  In Access 2000 and 2003, I could press F4 (or Alt-Enter) and then type to change the value or the selected property, or use the arrow keys to navigate. In Access 2010 it seems like I'm forced to use the mouse for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Its almost same in Access 2010 too

```
F4          - Toggle the property sheet
F6          - Switch between the windows, or between design panes / properties / etc
ALT + ENTER - Display a property sheet
```

Have a look at this [Access 2010 Video](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2010-keyboard-shortcuts-ii-access-keys-RZ102810191.aspx?section=5) and [LIST OF SHORTCUT KEYS ACCESS 2010](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Access_2010.html)

Comment: F4 and Alt-Enter (as stated in the question) don't focus the pane. F6 appears to work, if I'm willing to toggle it until it focuses what I want. Those definitely aren't the same as Access 2003, which focused the pane on F4.